# Последовательные Ajax-запросы для элементов массива

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть массив, который преобразую через `foreach`.
Допустим, есть массив данных с 10 записями и есть код:

```
function updateInfo()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/send.php",
        data: { "url": "<?php  echo $flink; ?>", "catid": "<?php echo $catid; ?>" },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Мне нужно эти данные по очереди передать в PHP файл. Как это сделать?
И желательно, чтобы следующие данные отправлялись только после получения ответа на предыдущий запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно передавать в функцию индекс `i` следующего элемента массива и после завершения (`.always()`, который отработает и в случае успеха предыдущего запроса, и в случае его неудачи) снова вызывать функцию с `i + 1` до тех пор, пока `i` не пробежит по всем элементам массива (`POST` заменён на `GET` для большей наглядности):

```js
var data = [10, 20, 30];
(function updateInfo(i) {
    if (i == data.length) {
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/send.php",
        data: { "url": "link" + data[i], "catid": "cat" + data[i] },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        }
    }).always(function() {
        updateInfo(i + 1);
    });
})(0);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Эм. Только как мне передать данные из массива? 
Сейчас в php передается link0 link1 и link2

Comment: ай. все. Затупил. +) Понял. =) Щас проверю

Comment: @Евгений это я опечатался: должно было быть `"url": "link" + data[i], "catid": "cat" + data[i]`. Исправил в ответе.

Comment: Да да. Я так и сделал=)

Answer (score 0):

Передайте js массив данных и вызовите первую отправку данных при получение ответа от сервера опять отправляйте данные такая маленькая рекурсия

Comment: Ну вот я и не знаю как это сделать. =)

Comment: @maksim, постарайтесь, пожалуйста, давать более развёрнутые ответы, в частности с примером кода.